# How to find the average of unique rows in python

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset

I want to find the average of unique values using data frames in python. 
For example, I have a dataset as:

```
 [c1]   [c2]
 foo    3.2 
 bar    4.3 
 foo    3.0 
 foo    2.3 
 bar    4.5 
 foo    1.9 
 bar    4.4
```

I want the output as:

Count of foo = 4 and average of foo is 2.6 //(i.e., (3.2+3.0+2.3+1.9)/4))

count of bar = 3 and average of bar is 4.4 //(i.e., (4.3+4.5+4.4)/3))

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you store your values in a list called data_averages:

```
import numpy as np # numpy module

# Your data_averages list that contains average

foo_list=[]
bar_list=[]

for i in range(len(data_averages)):
    if data_averages[i] == 'foo':
        foo_list.append(data_averages[i][1])
    else:
        bar_list.append(data_averages[i][1])

foo_avg = np.average(foo_list)
bar_list= np.average(bar_list)

print('Foo: ', foo_avg)
print('Bar: ', bar_avg)
```

Basically, your script checks the first column of your list (data_averages).

Your list might look something like this for your code to work:

```
# Make sure it is in following format: [string, float]
[['foo', 3.2],
['bar', 4.3],
['foo', 3.0]]
# And so on...
```

I hope this helps! If ever there is a bug in the code, please comment below, I'll try my best to respond ASAP.